# 502 Bad gateway on Nodejs application deployed on Kubernetes cluster

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, deployment, kubernetes-ingress, http-status-code-502

I am deploying nodejs application on kubernetes, After deployment pod is up and running, but when I am trying to access the application through ingress it is giving 502 bad gateway error.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3123
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

Deployment.yaml

```
---
  apiVersion: "apps/v1"
  kind: "Deployment"
  metadata: 
    name: "node-development"
    namespace: "development"
  spec: 
    selector: 
      matchLabels: 
        app: "node-development"
    replicas: 1
    template: 
      metadata: 
        labels: 
          app: "node-development"
      spec: 
        containers: 
          - 
            name: "node-development"
            image: "xxx"
            imagePullPolicy: "Always"
            env: 
              - 
                name: "NODE_ENV"
                value: "development"
            ports: 
              - 
                containerPort: 47033
```

service.yaml

```
---
  apiVersion: "v1"
  kind: "Service"
  metadata: 
    name: "node-development-service"
    namespace: "development"
    labels: 
      app: "node-development"
  spec: 
    ports: 
      - 
        port: 47033
        targetPort: 3123
    selector: 
      app: "node-development"
```

ingress.yaml

```
---
  apiVersion: "networking.k8s.io/v1"
  kind: "Ingress"
  metadata: 
    name: "node-development-ingress"
    namespace: "development"
    annotations: 
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/$1"
  spec: 
    rules: 
      - 
        host: "xxxx"
        http: 
          paths: 
            - 
              backend: 
                service:
                  name: "node-development"
                  port: 
                    number: 47033
              path: "/node-development/(.*)"
              pathType: "ImplementationSpecific"
```

With ingress or even with the pod cluster ip I am not being able to access application it is throwing 502 bad gateway nginx

Comment: Does it work when you do port-forwading for your service. also can you tell listen address for your nodejs application is it 0.0.0.0 or localhost?

Comment: Hi, No even with port forwarding, it is giving 502 bad gateway. Nodejs application is listening on port 3123, and I am accessing application with ingress path url. https://myhostname/nodejs-development/

Comment: What do logs say any error?

Comment: No errors in the log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue got resolved, I am using SSL in my application as a result it was not re-directing with the given ingress url.

Need to add below annotation in ingress.yaml file.

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
```